Calculus of scalar products
In a certain problem I have been given the following data: $ds^2 = u^2du^2 + 2ududv + 2dv^2$, which would be the First Fundamental Form of an unknown surface, given a parametrization $\alpha(u,v)$. I have been asked to find the six scalar products $\alpha_{ij}\cdot \alpha_k$ for $i,j,k \in \{u,v \}$.

Seeing $ds^2$ I have no problem at finding that $\alpha_{uu}\cdot \alpha_u = u$ and $\alpha_{vv} \cdot \alpha_{v} = 0$. However, when I try to find the mixed variable ones, I obtain $\alpha_{uu} \cdot \alpha_v + \alpha_{uv} \cdot \alpha_u = 1$ and $\alpha_{uv} \cdot \alpha_v + \alpha_{vv} \cdot \alpha_u = 0$. I have no idea of how find the remaining four ones.

I tried with adding them in order to use scalar product properties, but I haven't been able to reach the solution. I really need these calculations to introduce them into another exercise involving Christoffel symbols and geodesics. I would really appreciate any help or hint.

The term accompanying the $\mathrm dv^2$, should it be $2$ or $4$?

It is actually $2$, at least that is what appears in my exercise.

You forgot to take the other derivatives of $u^2$ and $2$, respectively.

Upon comparison, we know
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\alpha_u\cdot\alpha_u=u^2\hspace{1cm}(1)\\
&\alpha_u\cdot\alpha_v=u\hspace{1.25cm}(2)\\
&\alpha_v\cdot\alpha_v=2\hspace{1.3cm}(3)
\end{aligned}\right.$$
Differentiating each relation wrt $u$ and $v$ we obtain the following system of equations:
$$(1):\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\alpha_{uu}\cdot\alpha_u=u\\
&\alpha_{uv}\cdot\alpha_u=0
\end{aligned}\right.\enspace\enspace (2):\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\alpha_{uu}\cdot\alpha_v+\alpha_{u}\cdot\alpha_{vu}=1\\
&\alpha_{uv}\cdot\alpha_v+\alpha_{u}\cdot\alpha_{vv}=0
\end{aligned}\right.\enspace\enspace(3):\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\alpha_{uv}\cdot\alpha_v=0\\
&\alpha_{vv}\cdot\alpha_v=0
\end{aligned}\right.$$
Realizing that the scalar product is commutative and that $\alpha_{uv}=\alpha_{vu}$, substituting the results from $(1)$ and $(3)$ into $(2)$ we can deduce the remaining scalar products, $\alpha_{uu}\cdot\alpha_v$ and $\alpha_{vv}\cdot\alpha_u$:
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\alpha_{uu}\cdot\alpha_v=1\\
&\alpha_{vv}\cdot\alpha_u=0
\end{aligned}\right.$$
The relations you were missing to find these two scalar products were the ones @Ted Shifrin mentioned in the comment section.
